# Insert column values from different records in the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, Table_A with columns Id_A1 and Id_A2. I have another table, Table_B with columns Id and Description_B.

Now, I have with me some pairs of descriptions from Table_B, like ("desc 1","desc 3"), ("desc 1","desc 4"), ("desc 4","desc 2"), etc. And I want to insert the Ids corresponding to these descriptions in columns Id_A1 and Id_A2 of Table_A.

How to do this in a single insert statement per pair?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show some example data for both tables?

Comment: Table_A has no data. It has to be inserted. Schema for both tables is explained above. For Table_B you can assume it contains following descs - "desc 1", "desc 2", "desc 3", "desc 4" and "desc 5", etc.

Comment: I'm still not clear what is in table B. You have 2 columns; Id and Description_B. The descs you mention, are they in pairs in the Description_B column or 1 in the Id column and 1 in the Description_B column?

Comment: records for Table_B are -> [1,"desc 1"], [2,"desc 2"], [3,"desc 3"], [4,"desc 4"] and [5,"desc 5"]. Is it clear now?

Comment: So each record in Table_B is for example: Id = 1, Description_B = "desc 1"? Then how do your "pairs of descriptions from Table_B, like ("desc 1","desc 3"), ("desc 1","desc 4")..." appear? Sorry for not understanding.

Comment: No problem. You are right about what's there in Table_B. Now where do I get the pairs from? I get them from some text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this stored procedure would do it or you can just copy out the SQL and replace the parameters with what you're matching on if you prefer...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertPairs @Desc1 varchar(255), @Desc2 varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    Insert Into Table_A(Id_A1, Id_A2)
    SELECT
            (SELECT id from Table_B where Description_b=@Desc1) as IDA1,
            (SELECT id from Table_B where Description_b=@Desc2) as IDA2
END
```

Then call it as exec dbo.ups_InsertPairs 'desc 1','desc 3'

Note it's a single sql statement but there would be no way of doing it without multiple selects one way or another.